# How to set path on 'submit' button for saving uploaded file in local drive as 'uploaded photos' folder in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am new to AngularJS and Node.js. I want to upload and save an image file in local drive in a folder named `uploaded image` when clicking the submit button.

I am trying to fix it for past 10 days but I can't make it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Express [multer middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Refer: [28797965](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797965/expressjs-multer-upload-image-to-server)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great article that explains it perfectly: http://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/ajax-file-upload-node-js/

Basically, use a service called Multer like webpandit said above. It's a bit tricky to understand at first, but the link to the article above gives you all the code you need.

Comment: thanks for your replay dude...!!! but quite difficult to understand as am new to AngularJs,. but i am doing perfectly more then this in other process/modules of my project... now am concentrating on creating PDF's and download process...!!!